# Problem with rendering a custom component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I try to create a custom component for my application with emberJS, I have followed the quickstart tutoriel and now I try to create a upload button as a component.

It seems I don't have code issues but my component don't render on my main page. I have use the ember component generator to create it

here my upload-button.hbs :

```html
<button type="button">{{@buttonText}}</button>
```

now my upload-button.js :

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    actions: {
        showExplorer(){
            alert()
        }
    }
});
```

for the moment I simply put a `alert()` method in `showExplorer()`

and now my main page, application.hbs :

```html
<upload-button @buttonText="Uploader un fichier" {{action "showExplorer"}}/>

{{outlet}}
```

I expect to see my button but I just have a blank page with no code error.

I suspect that's a really stupid mistake but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you decided to try out Ember.js :) Your `upload-button.hbs` and `upload-button.js` file looks good. However, there are a couple of issues here.

- The component, when invoked using the angle-bracket syntax (`<... />`), the name should be **CamelCased** to distinguish between HTML tags and Ember components. Hence, we need to invoke the `upload-button` component as `<UploadButton />`.
- You defined your action, `showExplorer`, inside the component (`upload-button.js`) file, but, referenced in the `application.hbs` file. The data in the backing component file can only be accessed inside the component's `.hbs` file because of the isolated nature of the component architecture. Also, we can only attach an action using `{{action}}` modifier to a DOM element and not to the component itself. So,

we need to remove the action binding from `application.hbs` file,

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}

<UploadButton @buttonText="Uploader un fichier"/>
```

and add the same inside the `upload-button.hbs` file:

```
{{!-- upload-button.hbs --}}

<button type="button" {{action "showExplorer"}}>{{@buttonText}}</button>
```

A working model can be found in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ember-313-dlw9x)

Hope you find learning Ember, a fun process!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I try it and it worked ! Now I better understand how a component work and I would pay more attention with the naming of my component :)

Comment: glad it helped @Pixelyoda. If the solution works, consider it markings accepted ;) (tick icon on the left side to the answer)